# Something wrong: readerActivity.SendPostRequest cannot be converted to Context

Tags: android, web, send

im trying to send data, and after i get it, im trying to create an elemenet, but there is error like:

**Error:(121, 48) error: incompatible types: readerActivity.SendPostRequest cannot be converted to Context**

but without getting this data from website - works fine

```
    public class SendPostRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute(){}

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        try {

            String book = getIntent().getExtras().getString("book");
            String page = "2";

            URL url = new URL("http://website.org/test"); // here is your URL path

            JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
            postDataParams.put("one", book);
            postDataParams.put("two", page);
            Log.e("params",postDataParams.toString());

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new
                        InputStreamReader(
                        conn.getInputStream()));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line="";

                while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }

                in.close();
                return sb.toString();

            }
            else {
                return new String("false : "+responseCode);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        LinearLayout llMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_reader);

        String text = result;
        String[] parts = text.split("</br></br>");
        for (String part : parts)
        {
            FlowLayout ab = new FlowLayout(this);
            llMain.addView(ab);
            ab.setPadding(1,1,1,35);
            FlowLayout fab = new FlowLayout(this);
            ab.addView(fab);

            String[] words = part.split(" ");
            for (String word : words)
            {
                TextView btnNew = new TextView(this);
                btnNew.setText(word.toString());
                ab.addView(btnNew);
                btnNew.setPadding(20,15,20,25);
                btnNew.setTextSize(19);
            }

        }

    }
}

public String getPostDataString(JSONObject params) throws Exception {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    Iterator<String> itr = params.keys();

    while(itr.hasNext()){

        String key= itr.next();
        Object value = params.get(key);

        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "UTF-8"));

    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: I use nearly the same code you use... did you figure out how to implement onProgressUpdate() within the code while posting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its done, i just changed

```
FlowLayout ab = new FlowLayout(this);
```

to

```
FlowLayout ab = new FlowLayout(getApplicationContext());
```

and it works fine